# When you break a glass block/pane can you get it back?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have never been able to tell if I could break glass and get it back (like dirt, wood, cobblestone etc). Is this possible at all? is it possible in version 1.6.2.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Arqade! I've removed the part about the village, as it's a separate question. This question [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53387/what-makes-a-villager-spawn/53424#53424) may be useful for what you want. Otherwise feel free to ask another question :)

Answer (score 28):

With regular tools? No; once you place a glass block/pane and hit it with regular tools or your fist - it shatters and you get nothing.

*However*, if you have a tool enchanted with [silk touch](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Silk_Touch), glass blocks and panes will drop their respective item pickups (silk touch also allows you to get other fancy stuff from various blocks - like mycelium, grass, huge mushroom blocks, ore blocks, and glowstone).

Comment: Glowstone, too.

Comment: And most importantly, ice!

Comment: But not spawners.

Comment: @user52788 - If this answer has helped you, you can mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the checkmark beneath this answer's vote count. This awards the answerer and yourself with some extra rep, and helps show future visitors what worked for you, should they have the same problem :)

Comment: Glass panes are extremely cheap and easy to make, though.  I don't think they're worth putting extra wear on a silk touch-enchanted tool to recover.

Comment: @AJMansfield - I guess it depends what's more valuable to you. If you need to break a lot of panes, if you're far from a source of sand or running low on coal/charcoal it might be more beneficial to use a silk touched pick. I tend to enchant books first so i can pick and choose my enchantments, and you can combine them in an anvil to get better combos. My current silk touch pick has Unbreaking 2 as well for example

Comment: Does it matter which tool gets silk touch?

Comment: @D.Tanya AFAIK, the tool doesn't matter. With silk touch the tool only matters for breaking time, and tool durability. (With glass, breaking time with bare hands is 0.45sec, wiki doesn't list any better times with tools)

Comment: Oh my god it's the same person from 4 years ago. Anyhow, thank you. Just wanted to add that I've put it on a pickaxe and it does work indeed.